# How do I translate unicode(s, "utf-8") to work in both Python 2 and Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode, porting

How do I translate **unicode(s, "utf-8")** to work in both Python 2 and Python 3?

**unicode()** was removed in Python 3 because all **str** are Unicode but **str()** does not take a second parameter like **unicode()** does so it is not a valid substitute.

I tried:

```
>>> for s in ("Luesai", u"Lüsai"):
...     print(s)
...     a = unicode(s, "utf-8")
...     print(a)
...     b = unicode(s).encode("utf-8")
...     print(b)
...     print(a == b)
...
Luesai
Luesai
Luesai
True
Lüsai
TypeError: decoding Unicode is not supported
```

Comment: Your test program is based on many assumptions that don't hold in Python 3. It will need to be redone even once you get a satisfactory answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a byte string, the way to translate it in both 2 and 3 is to use `decode`:

```
a = s.decode("utf-8")
```

Comment: This answer assumes that the input is a byte string which is not the case with **u"Lüsai"** in our test data.

Comment: @cclauss that's because your test data is incorrect. If your data is already a Unicode string there's no need to convert it; your question is ill-formed.